# Failed to find a fingerprint device

Tags: fingerprint-reader

Recently I bought hp probook 450 g6 and installed ubuntu 18.04. The problem is that I can't find the fingerprint device using `lsusb`. I contacted the hp team through their website, and confirmed that the fingerprint reader is by persona digital. I have tried `fingerprint-gui` and `fprintd` but all failed to find the fingerprint device.

Can someone please, help me?